# Does Dotnet Core implement Composition Root discovery?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm just starting a new project using .net core (1.1) and want to register the services in sub-assemblies with the DI container.  In previous projects, I have registered services in the assembly the concrete class exists in, this allows me to have a public interface but a private (or internal) implementation.

I can't see a way to implement this in .net core, without writing some sort of assembly discovery function it myself (not difficult I know).

AutoFac uses Modules, Ninject uses NinjectModule, LightInject uses ICompositionRoot, is there an equivilent in .net core (without substituting the DI framework).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with having an internal implementation?

Comment: There's no need to have the concrete implementation exposed beyond the assembly.

Comment: There is no need to hide them either.

Comment: Yes there is.  I don't want less experienced developers trying to access classes they shouldn't be accessing directly.  Potentially, there are multiple implementations of the same interface that should only be instantiated from the DI, if implementations are public, it's easy to just pick the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Module like Autofac or Castle Windsor.

You might be able to do import Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection from the assembly you want to have internal implementation and:

Expose an extension method like:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection c) 
{
    c.Register<IPublicInterface,IInternalImplementation>();
}
```

At the application you would just call the AddMyServices at ConfigureServices and the internal classes to that assembly will not be visible.

That's just an idea, haven't tried though. Also,yYou can easily plug Autofac if you are going fancy with DI. There's a lot Autofac offer that you don't get from the built-in DI and if it's a big app, it won't take long until you need it.